# Make several parent page thumbnails listing , order by desc

Tags: php, wordpress

I have page with page listings and this pages are parent pages and they have child pages, so this main page using my code is listing this child pages thumbnails. But the problem is that it is listing like this - Example : I have 3 ID-s 403,414,417. First it is listing all child pages thumbnais of 403,after 414,and at last 414. It means if I create page today with parent page 414, it will put this thumbnail after all 403 thumbnails when I need it to be the first in wrapper. So in one word I need to order this thumbnails by postdate "desc" but not separated by this ID blocks, I need it like one object ordering. I'll show code what I have maybe someone know the solution.

**What I have**

```
<div id="archive-thumbnails-listing" >
    <?php $pages = array();
    foreach (array(417, 403, 414) as $id) {
    $pages = array_merge($pages, get_pages(array('child_of' => $id ,'sort_column' => 'post_date', 'sort_order' => 'desc' )));
    } ?>

    <?php foreach ($pages as $page): ?>
    <div class="thumb12wrap">
    <a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink($page->ID); ?>">
    <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($page->ID, 'full'); ?></a>
    <div class="thumbwrapper88">
    <div class="shade23desc" ><a class="desc"  href="<?php echo get_the_permalink($page->ID); ?>"><?php echo $page->post_title; ?></a></div>
    <a class="descarea"  href="<?php echo get_the_permalink($page->ID); ?>"></a>
    </div>
    </div>   
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you please ask your query clearly because not getting anything all are messed up?

Comment: I tried my best, but I'll try one more time:D okay I have as you see page listing of 3 IDS (417,403,414). this page listing works like this : first it is getting posts from id 417(ordering by date "desc"), after it is geting all posts from id 403(ordering by date "desc") and after it is getting all posts from 414(ordering by date "desc"). It means when I add a page to id 403 it will put this page after ID 417 posts, when I need this new page to be first in listing, not after posts ID417 , I need it at the start of listing, not after.

Comment: Is there a way to split, merge this listings by a date, like when I create new page with id 414 it will put it in page listings  at the start ? I will attach picture to make my question more clear. THANKS

Comment: http://imgur.com/K4avow0  hre you can see example. I need this new item(on picture) be first in a listing because it is last added page(last shooting)

Comment: ok do one thing start chat. because i'm not on desk so i cant give example right now. but help you by chat.

Comment: I dont know this function of stacker. I found chat with different rooms , in what room i have to login?

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/89692/make-sevaral-parent-page?tab=general join me on this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89762/discussion-between-kausha-mehta-and-user3852799).

Answer (score 0):

You have to write the code like below, after yesterday's chat i found the bug and solve it. So replace your code with below.

```
<?php
$pages = array();
foreach (array(403, 417, 414) as $id) {
    $pages[] = get_pages(array('child_of' => $id ,'sort_column' => 'post_date', 'sort_order' => 'desc' ));
}
?> 
<?php
if (count($pages)) {
    for ($k = 0; $k < count($pages); $k++) {
        foreach ($pages[$k] as $page):
            ?> 
            <div class="thumb12wrap"> 
                <a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink($page->ID); ?>"> 
                    <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($page->ID, 'full'); ?></a> 
                <div class="thumbwrapper88"> 
                    <div class="shade23desc" ><a class="desc" href="<?php echo get_the_permalink($page->ID); ?>"><?php echo $page->post_title; ?></a></div> 
                    <a class="descarea" href="<?php echo get_the_permalink($page->ID); ?>"></a> 
                </div> 
            </div> 
            <?php
        endforeach;
    }
}
?>
```

Hope this will work for you, Thanks!